# How to fix the error "file_get_contents was found in the file functions.php"?

Tags: theme-development, wp-filesystem

I am building a wordpress theme, I reach the step of finalization.

Right now, I am struggling to fix an error raised by Theme Check, :

> file_get_contents was found in the file functions.php File operations
>   should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem
>   calls.

Here the code:

```
function theme_critical() {
  $critical_css = file_get_contents( get_template_directory() . '/css/critical.css');
  echo '<style>' . $critical_css . '</style>';
}
```

Basicaly, this code take the content of a CSS file, to print it in the header. This is a critical css.

I searched, but I could not find a way to use WP_filesystem to simply to the same thing than file_get_content does.

Is anyone already faced this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## To Add External Atylesheet:

Generally speaking, you should use the [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) function to add external stylesheet to your theme.

```
function wpse259600_add_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_critical', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/critical.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse259600_add_style' );
```

---

## To Add Internal Stylesheet:

However, if (for whatever reason) you have to add internal stylesheet (i.e. printing the entire CSS file within the HTML `<head>` tag using the `<style>` tag), then you may use `inclue_once` like below:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse259600_internal_css_print' );
function wpse259600_internal_css_print() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    // this will also allow you to use PHP to create dynamic css rules
    include_once get_template_directory() . '/css/critical.css';
    echo '</style>';
}
```

This will not generate warning in [`theme check`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/). Although, I wouldn't recommend this. If you want to add custom CSS this way, you better save it to the database with customizer theme options and then add it with `wp_add_inline_style` function along with your theme's main CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be echoing your CSS styles in the `<head>`. You should be using [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Add something like this to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_259600_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse_259600_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-critical', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/critical.css' );
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `get_template_directory()` that way, it needs URL, should be `get_template_directory_uri()`.